# How to solve RxJS range overlap?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I have two Observable Sequence named `source1` and `source2`.
I want to match `source2` with `source1` so that `source2` is not alllowed to overlap `source1`:

```
// source1 = Rx.Observalble.range(...)
// source2 = Rx.Observable.range(...)

           |.............|            // `source1` range
      |--------|                      // false: `source2` is overlapped
                      |--------|      // false: `source2` is overlapped
              |--------|              // false: `source2` is overlapped
//|-------|                           // true: `source2` is not overlapped
//                        |--------|  // true: `source2` is not overlapped
```

My solution is to use `Rx.Observable#first` and `Rx.Observable#last` as the following:

```
source1 = Rx.Observable.range(100, 50)
source2 = Rx.Observable.range(150, 10)

pred1 = source1.first().zip(source2.last(), (a, b) => a >= b)
pred2 = source1.last().zip(source2.first(), (a, b) => a <= b)

// Have to use #combineLatest to get it done, don't know why 
// #zip doesnt work. Uncomment the line below to check

// pred1.zip(pred2, (a, b) => a || b).subscribe(x => console.log(x))

pred1.combineLatest(pred2, (a, b) => a || b).subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

I am looking forward to seeing a solution using other operator such as `#reduce`, `#scan`, `#flatMap`, `#concatMap` or `#filter`.

The reason is, the above example just compares two ranges. What if I have an **array of range** needed to be checked if they are overlap each other. Thinking about a `reducer` that would be helpful in this case.

```
// `array_of_range` could be an array of observable sequences
let source = Rx.Observalbe.fromArray(array_of_range)
source.scan((prev, curr) => {
  // Do magic here
}, false)
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x)) //=> Check if any two ranges in the `source` are overlapped or not
```

And **if the ranges are overlapped, how to `transform` these ranges into optimal smaller new ranges so that they don't overlap each other**. I know it is not trivial answer so any suggestions are appreciated!

**Update 01:**
Thanks to @joneshf, The *first problem* could be solved as the following:

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.range(0, 10),
  Rx.Observable.range(11, 20),
  Rx.Observable.range(21, 25)
  )
  .scan(({intersected, set}, n) => ({intersected: set.has(n), set: set.add(n)}), 
  {intersected: false, set: new Set()}
  )
  .pluck('intersected')
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev || curr)
  .subscribe(x => x ? ‘There was an intersection’ : ‘No intersection’)
```

Any further discussion are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can group by index (with `zip`)

```
zip(range(1, 10), range(5, 10), range(10, 10)).subscribe(z => {
  console.log(z);
});
//=> [ 1 , 5 , 10 ]
//=> [ 2 , 6 , 11 ]
//=> [ 3 , 7 , 12 ]
//=> [ 4 , 8 , 13 ]
//=> [ 5 , 9 , 14 ]
//=> [ 6 , 10, 15 ]
//=> [ 7 , 11, 16 ]
//=> [ 8 , 12, 17 ]
//=> [ 9 , 13, 18 ]
//=> [ 10, 14, 19 ]
```

Then you can reconstruct each range **if and only if** its number has never been seen before:

| Input | 1st rg. | 2nd rg. | 3rd rg. | Master Set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1, 5, 10] | [1] | [5] | [10] | Set{1 5 10} |
| [2, 6, 11] | [1, 2] | [5, 6] | [10, 11] | Set{1 2 5 6 10 11} |
| [3, 7, 12] | [1, 2, 3] | [5, 6, 7] | [10, 11, 12] | Set{1 2 3 5 6 7 10 11 12} |
| … | … | … | … | … |

```js
const solution$ =
  zip(range(1, 10), range(5, 10), range(10, 10)).pipe(
    reduce(([rg, st], ns) => {
      ns.forEach((n, i) => {
        if (!st.has(n)) {
          rg[i] ??= [];
          rg[i].push(n);
          st.add(n);
        }
      });
      return [rg, st];
    }, [[], new Set])
  );

solution$.subscribe(([rg]) => {
  console.log('Optimal ranges:',
    rg.map(r => `[${r[0]}-${r[r.length-1]}]`).join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-MlqMFvHwgWJ1vfts5fdC2WzxDaIXWfYuAd9Tb2lobtF61Gk+HIRDrbtxgasBSM9lZgOK9ilwK9LqFIYEV+k0IA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
const {zip, range} = rxjs;
const {reduce} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```